# How to continue mounting if condition is met?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react and I have componentWillMount which looks like this

```
componentWillMount() {
  axios.get('/user').then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.user)
    if (response.data.user) {
    } else {
      this.props.history.replace('/signup');
    }
  });
}
```

Notice this line here in the code.

```
if (response.data.user) {
        }
```

Now, How can I make my container render if the condition is met?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the `user` variable in the component state once you received it in `then` method, and later you can use it in your render method:

```
import React from 'react'

class App extends React.Component { 
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { user: null }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('/user').then(response => {

      if (response.data.user) {
        this.setState({ user: reaponse.data.user )}
      } else {
        this.props.history.replace('/signup')
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    // Do something with the user
    if (this.state.user) {
      return <div>{this.state.user.name}</div>
    }

    return <div />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy, render conditionally based on state.

```
import React from "react";

class ExampleComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  state={ user: null }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
    if(!prevState.user && state.user){
      this.props.history.replace('/signup');
    }

   else return null;
  }

  componentWillMount() {
      axios.get('/user').then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.user)
        if (response.data.user) {
           this.setState({ user: response.data.user )}
        }
     });
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.state;
    return user ? <div>have user, can return null</div> : <div>loading user</div>
  }
}

export default ExampleComponent;
```